# Do Opus And AAC Use Artistic License To Improve Sound Quality By Sacrificing Accuracy?

Tags: synthesis, mp3, aac-m4a

I was reading a forum thread the other day and came across a post which claims that unlike MP3, other codecs such as Opus and AAC "[[invent] audio data that's not accurate to the source](https://getmusicbee.com/forum/index.php?topic=21945.0)" by "[[synthesizing] high-end frequency data](https://getmusicbee.com/forum/index.php?topic=21945.0)". Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

You can read up on how the Opus codec works here: http://opus-codec.org/

Opus is entirely open-source, so you can even read the source-code to determine how it works.

Here is a paper on how MP3 and AAC work: https://www.iis.fraunhofer.de/content/dam/iis/de/doc/ame/conference/AES-17-Conference_mp3-and-AAC-explained_AES17.pdf

These information sources should provide the insight you are seeking.

And by the way, the post to which you refer is nonsense.